# computer won't boot from DVD, how do I upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I have an old computer that is still running 10.04 - quite happily - and I was curious what newer versions of Ubuntu offered. Obviously can't upgrade, 14.03.3 was downloaded and put on DVD, but the computer won't boot from DVD. Or it does not offer that boot option in the BIOS setup, although it does offer USB.

How do I get it to junk 10.04 and install 14.03.3?

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious but, you know, do you have a USB thumb drive?

Comment: If you have a fellow friend who has a computer from which you can boot that DVD,  take your hard drive to them, connect to their PC ( make sure you remove their hard drive, so that you accidentally don't install Ubuntu on their computer ) , install 14.04 LTS , and once done, reconnect everything, take hard drive back.  I've a 2.5'' HDD which used to reside in my Toshiba A215 laptop, but now resides in an old HP Slimline.  As a bonus, you get to test who your real friends are :) Alternatively , just ask them to make a bootable USB

Answer (score 0):

First, download the ISO file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Then, go to the system menu, administration, and select 'Create a USB startup disk'. Select a blank USB drive to use, and your Ubuntu 14.04.3 ISO file. Click the Make Startup Disk button, and wait for it to finish. Once finished, you can boot from your USB drive and start the upgrade.

Source: http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=1645

Answer (score 0):

OK, did all that, changed the BIOS to boot from USB as first option, saved it, powered down, powered up with the precious stick in place and......
10.04 pops up again. How do I kill this thing?

Comment: You may have to set the BIOS option in the same boot as the one in which you install it.  In other words: power off -> insert USB -> power on -> hold key to enter BIOS -> set boot order to BIOS first -> exit BIOS -> continue boot to USB

Answer (score 0):

tried that, but then noticed that USB option in BIOS has several variants, 
USB FDD
USB CD ROM
USB HDD

I've been trying the FDD and CD rom options but it just boots up 10.04 every time. Does it matter what USB slot I use? I feel a FORMAT C: coming on.